# Rails 3.x authentication using existing table fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have Rails 3.2.11 application that i need to hook up with login. The Devise Database Authenticatable would have been ok except:

1. I can't create table/fields and need to use existing fields(Devise wants to create user model).
2. Instead of user model, i have to use "existing model (student) with email and password fields.

Would any of you Rails guru tell me how to customize Devise or if to use something different.
Basic requirement is: use login system where someone has to register but use existing table/fields.

Thank you

Comment: Consider to use Sorcery instead of Devise (http://github.com/NoamB/sorcery). It does what you want.

Comment: Don't know how this works and if it has the above items(#1,2).

Comment: It has. And much more. The learning curve is harder, though.

Comment: Additionally, devise can be configured to use existing tables, you don't need to run the task that creates the user tables.  Within the devise configuration, you can specify the existing user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize devise as much as you want. Railscasts #210 gives information about customization options. You can create a devise model with any name you want btw. For example, you can do:

```
rails generate devise Student
```

If you want a Student model. Pretty much everything in Devise can be customized, altough some changes are easier then others. You could also get all the controllers from devise at github and customize or just override them in your own application. The devise wiki has a lot of information about customizing:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki

I can also recommend the revised railscast #250 authentication from scratch (also railscasts available for authorization from scratch), if you want full control on all your authentication options.

Comment: Peter appreciated the info. I'm checking this out tonight/tomm and will accept if it works

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer if you can't add fields to your table, Devise is not a authentication choice. It needs certain basic specific fields to work.

You can set Devise with a specific model name, as Peter de Ridder points out. But, without these required fields, several wild errors will show up (like "missing column" among others more cryptic).

Note that in this Devise's wiki article refers to these fields as **required**:

> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns

Comment: I been testing this and after some progress, stuck at: undefined method `authenticate_student!'

Comment: Yes, that is the kind of _wild errors_ you will get. Without access to tables and fields, Rails is powerless!